# How to send the output of CSH script to a text editor?

Tags: linux, csh

I found a pretty cool CSH script at work that makes a frequently used query to Postgres a little more friendly --- except that it dumps the output to the shell.   This is the part of the script generating the output:

```
psql "select datauri from grid where datauri like '%${1}%'" | awk -F '/' '{print $3 "\t" $4 "\t" $7 "\t" $8 "\t" $9 "\t" $10 "\t" $11}'
```

The name of the script is "DB"

I've tried sending this output directly to a text editor to make the output easier to deal with:

```
$ db get stuff | emacs -nw
```

I only get a blank emacs ( vi, or gedit ).

Is there a way I can alter the script, or something else, to have the output sent directly to a text editor rather than just the shell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `vim`, you can do this:

```
$ db get stuff | vim -
```

The `-` tells `vim` to read its text input from stdin.

Answer (score 1):

You can run the script form withing emacs, in fact, and it would create a new buffer for its output. Just use <kbd>M-!</kbd> (which runs `shell-command`), specify the command, and then switch to the `*Shell Command Output*` buffer.

Answer (score 0):

By vim's 'r' command, output of a command can be inserted into a specific line like `:10r !db get stuff`. '10r' inserts into 11th line and '!' fetches output of the following command.